# Is it good practice to pass object as generic type ( IEnumerable<object> Get(string ViewName) )in MVC Web API?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api

I have to pass a the name of Database View as a parameter to the web Api.
According to the passed view name, It will return the json data to the client.

The approach that I am using is as below:

```
public IEnumerable<object> Get(string ViewName)
    {
        using (EnDBContext context = new EnDBContext())
        {
            switch (ViewName)
            {
                case "V_R_RESULT":

                    return Mapper.Map<List<vmRResult>>(context.V_R_RESULT.ToList());


                case "V_REL_SHIP":

                    return Mapper.Map<List<vmRelShip>>(context.V_REL_SHIP.ToList());
}

 return null;
}
```

Please let me know the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

also you can return `dynamic` instead `IEnumerable<object>`, but I think the best way is: split the code action in two or more actions depending on the number of case that you have, so you can declare the exact type of return that each action needs.